# why the R while loops can't implement with shiny frame work?

Tags: r, loops, while-loop, shiny

I am trying to create a simple text listing UI on the shiny dashboard. For this, I made an R function, which needs to store each text inputs to store in a list.

```r
readtasks <- function() {

  df <- list()
  while(TRUE) {
    tasks <- readline(prompt="type your tasks: ")
    # stop reading if no text was typed in
    if (tasks == '')
      break

    # add the read data to the bottom of the list
    df <- append(df,tasks)
  }
  print(df)
}
```

The function works g,ood for my needs, but when it comes to shiny it shows so many errors. I am eagerly want to know, how this while loop can efficiently implement to shiny. I search a lot in google and StackOverflow about this.if possible please give me an example.

Thank you

I try to made a shiny app with the above function

```
ui<- fluidPage(

  textInput(inputId = "text","add"),
  actionButton("button",label = "enter"),
  verbatimTextOutput("list")
)



server<- function(input,output,session){


       df<- list()
    while(TRUE) {
      tasks <- input$text
        # stop reading if no year was typed in
        if (tasks == '')
          break

      # add the read data to the bottom of the dataframe

      df <- append(df,tasks)

      output$list<- renderprint({df})


      }

}

shinyApp(ui = ui,server = server)
```

but it crashes with the following error

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:7598
Warning: Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext: Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
  61: stop
  60: .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext
  59: getCurrentContext
  55: .subset2(x, "impl")$get
  54: $.reactivevalues
  52: server [#6]
Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
```

It is really helpfull to know to execute the functions with while loops

Once again thank you

Comment: If you're writing an app in `shiny`, do you expect the user to interact with both the web interface and the R console? This might be acceptable when running R locally (e.g., in RStudio), but this cannot work when deployed (shinyapps.io, rstudio connect, shiny server, etc).

Comment: yes you are right, but in which way I have to implement such a code in shiny, can you suggest any specific function for doing this.

Comment: Without a lot more context, I'm going to have to say "it's certainly possible, learn `shiny`". That doesn't help you much (and is intended to be at least a little funny), but there are so many ways that this could be done, and many of them are "poor practice".